# How to add .htm to email body using win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I need to use `win32com.client` to make an email where I add a signature with the `.htm` extension to the `mail.HtmlBody`. However, each time I do this, I get `UnicodeDecodeError`.

In other words, how do I correct the `UnicodeDecodeError` problem and add my string & htm file to the `HtmlBody`?

```
    self.mail = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application').CreateItem(0)
    self.curText = str(self.email.currentText())
    self.projectNameT = ' '.join(self.curText.split(' ')[7:])
    self.mail.To = 'ABC@XYZ.com' 
    self.mail.Subject = "Subject: " + str(self.projectNameT)
    self.someStr = 'Hello ' 
    self.html_url = open("SomePath//Signature.htm",encoding = 'utf16')
    self.data = self.html_url.read()
    self.mail.HtmlBody = self.someStr  + ('<p>self.data</p>')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a signature in using python and fully programatically, [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) exposes the [RDOSignature](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosignature.htm) object which implements ApplyTo method (it deals with signature image files and merges HTML styles). Because with the outlook security patch, a lot is unable to be done inherrently, so you must work around this before you can procede as normal

Comment: I have the HTM file tho, how do I upload a physically saved htm extension file